# std::remove_const with const references

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std

Why does `std::remove_const` not convert `const T&` to `T&`? This admittedly rather contrived example demonstrates my question:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    std::remove_const<const int&>::type b(a);

    // This assertion fails
    static_assert(
        !std::is_same<decltype(b), const int&>::value,
        "Why did remove_const not remove const?"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

The above case is trivially easy to fix, so for context, imagine the following:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Selector
{
    constexpr static const char* value = "default";
};

template <typename T>
struct Selector<T&>
{
    constexpr static const char* value = "reference";
};

template <typename T>
struct Selector<const T&>
{
    constexpr static const char* value = "constref";
};

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << Selector<typename std::remove_const<const int&>::type>::value
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, I'd expect `reference` to be shown, rather than `constref`.

Comment: Remember, there's no such thing as a const reference, only a reference to const.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`std::remove_const` removes *top level* `const`-qualifications. In `const T&`, which is equivalent to `T const&`, the qualification is not top-level: in fact, it does not apply to the reference itself (that would be meaningless, because references are immutable by definition), but to the referenced type.

Table 52 in Paragraph 20.9.7.1 of the C++11 Standard specifies, regarding `std::remove_const`:

> The member typedef type shall name the same type as `T` except that
> any **top-level** const-qualifier has been removed.
> [ *Example*: `remove_const<const volatile int>::type` evaluates to
> `volatile int`, whereas `remove_const<const int*>::type` evaluates
> to `const int*`. — *end example* ]

In order to strip `const` away, you first have to apply `std::remove_reference`, *then* apply `std::remove_const`, and then (if desired) apply `std::add_lvalue_reference` (or whatever is appropriate in your case).

**NOTE:** As [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo) mentions in the comment, you may consider [using an alias template such as `Unqualified`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16749618/9945076) to perform the first two steps, i.e. strip away the reference, then strip away the `const`- (and `volatile-`) qualification.

Comment: The first two are often grouped together under an `Unqualified<T>` alias.

Comment: Also, std::decay_t<const int&> yields int.