# Get base type of a template type (remove const/reference/etc.)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is there a type traits template which returns the *base type* of a given type. By *base type* I mean the type with all value modifiers, const, volatile, etc. stripped off.  For example, using a hypothetical traits function:

```
base<int>::type == int
base<int const>::type == int
base<int&>::type == int
```

I'm aware of `remove_const` and `remove_reference` and am currently just using them in combination. I'm wondering if however there exists already such a trait and perhaps if there is a proper name to what I am referring?

Comment: `typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type`?

Comment: @AndyProwl, yes, that's what I do now... I guess that does cover all ways of referencing the type.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would probaby define a type alias such as:

```
template<typename T>
using base_type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;
```

Note that, in an article no longer available, [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) proposed the name `Unqualified` for such a type alias.

The standard type trait [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), on the other hand does the same as the above *and* something more for array and function types, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: How does the `Unqualified` one compare to `std::common_type` (I did [test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b36ef298b0537eb2841c01d881685e7a-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f) it, even with [both traits](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=91fd0a114c9d0e6835133fb5062f01c8-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f))?

Comment: @chris: Huh, that's confusing. Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the Standard specify that `common_type<T>` should be `T` when there is only one type argument?

Comment: I know it works as an identity template, but from what I've seen, all it removes is cv and references. I don't know if it does that to anything else.

Comment: @chris: My point is, according to the Standard it shouldn't be removing cv and references, so that's perhaps a bug?

Comment: [R. Martinho’s wheels library uses the type trait `wheels::RemoveCv` for this.](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/17aee21522ce8d07c7a74b138e528fadf04d62ed/include/wheels/meta/type_traits.h%2B%2B?at=default)

Comment: @AndyProwl, I checked and MSVC does a true identity template for it. I thought those seemed like they collided. There's no way this could have not been reported as a bug to GCC by now (seems really unlikely).

Comment: @chris: That is weird indeed. I checked the C++14 Draft and it also specifies that it should behave like an identity trait

Comment: I got a bit confused when trying to use the code of this answer : if you want base_type to behave like the std type traits, you have to remove the last `::type`, right ?
because in the current form to use it you need to write `base_type<T>` and not `base_type<T>::type`

Comment: Same remark as Macke on std::decay, since the answer was posted, C++14 added the helper types with suffix _t to automatically get the ::type, so you can write std::remove_cv_t, std::remove_reference_t and remove the two '::type'

Answer (score 11):

try `std::decay`. It mimicks what happens when you pass arguments to functions by value: strips top-level cv-qualifiers, references, converts arrays to pointers and functions to function pointers.

Regards,
&rzej

Comment: even better with `std::decay_t<..>`, directly gives the "raw" type. :)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously it depends on what exactly you want to remove from the type. [std::decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) could be what you are looking for (removes references, `const/volatile`, decays array to pointer and function to function pointer). If you don't want the array to pointer and function to functionpointer decay,  you need to stick with `std::remove_reference` and `std::remove_cv` (removes `const` and `volatile`). Of course you could combine the two into your own typetrait to make using it easier.

Comment: c++20 has introduced just that.  It's called [`std::remove_cvref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref).

Answer (score 1):

C++20 gives us `std::remove_cvref_t` for this purpose.

Before, you could do `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>`.

There's also `std::decay_t`, but it additionally converts arrays/functions to pointers, etc.