# Unexpected result with partial template specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have encountered some unexpected results while playing around with my personal formatting library. I have reduced the code to the listing you can find below or on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cc8bd4a4f9c12b7).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct executioner {
    inline static void exec( const T & ){
        std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct executioner<std::pair<T1, T2> > {
    inline static void exec( const std::pair<T1, T2> & t ){
        std::cout << "pair" << std::endl;
        executioner<T1>::exec( t.first );
        executioner<T2>::exec( t.second );
    }
};

template <template <typename ...> class Container,
      typename ... Ts>
struct executioner<Container<Ts ...> > {
    inline static void exec( const Container<Ts ...> & c ){
        std::cout << "cont" << std::endl;
        auto it = c.begin();
        typedef decltype( * it ) ContainedType;
        executioner<ContainedType>::exec( * it );
    }
};

template <typename T> void execute( const T & t ){
    executioner<T>::exec( t );
}

int main(){
    std::map<int,std::string> aMap = { { 0, "zero" }, { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" } };
    execute( aMap );
}
```

Note that the code is reduced for demonstration, in the actual piece, I'd use the iterator in the variadic function to loop over the input container and call `executioner<ContainedType>::exec( * it );` for each of the container's elements.

Executing this code, I would expect the following output:

> cont
>   pair
>   generic

To my surprise, the specialisation for `std::pair` was not used, the actual output is:

> cont
>   generic

I very much doubt that this is a compiler bug (since it happens with both `gcc 4.9` and `clang 3.2`) and therefore I ask

> **What's the catch I haven't thought about?**

Comment: Your code specializes on `std::pair` not `std::map`.

Comment: @40two But `ContainedType` is `std::pair<int,std::string>` or at least it should be. Therefore I'd assume that the nested call `executioner<ContainedType>::exec( * it );` goes to the function specialised for `std::pair`.

Comment: maybe try `Container::value_type` for `ContainedType`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your variadic template code to the following:

```
template <template <typename ...> class Container,
  typename ... Ts>
struct executioner<Container<Ts ...> > {
  inline static void exec(const Container<Ts ...> & c){
    std::cout << "cont" << std::endl;
    auto it = c.begin();
    executioner<typename Container<Ts...>::value_type>::exec(*it);
  }
};
```

and your code will work as expected.

### Reason:

I'll try to demonstrate why `decltype` doesn't work as expected with an example:

```
template <template <typename ...> class Container,
      typename ... Ts>
struct executioner<Container<Ts ...> > {
    inline static void exec( const Container<Ts ...> & c ){
        std::cout << "cont" << std::endl;
        auto it = c.begin();
        typedef decltype( (*it) ) ContainedType;
        if(std::is_same<decltype(it->first), const int>::value) {
          std::cout << "IS CONST !!!" << std::endl;
        }
        executioner<ContainedType>::exec( * it );
    }
};
```

If you run substituting with the code above you'll see that conditional `std::is_same<decltype(it->first), const int>::value` is `true`. This means that the `*it` is of type `std::pair<const int, std::basic_string<...>>` and not `std::pair<int, std::basic_string<...>>`. Thus, your specialization "fails".

Comment: Bonus points: Why does this not work with `decltype( * it )` ?

Comment: @elemakil `*it` is of type reference to pair (`const std::pair<T1,T2>&`) which matches your generic `const T&`-case.

Comment: @elemakil : You specialize for `pair<>`, but `*it` is `pair<> const&`.

Comment: @djf @ildjarn Actually, I just checked using `typeid( * it ).name()` and `ContainedType` is `std::pair<int const, std::string>`. The const is in the pair...

Comment: @elemakil Then valueof typeid().name is implementation dependent. It's not the real type. Check out a modified [example which specializes on const& pair](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83bb03aa76ff7133). I think that works as you hoped

Comment: @djf Is it possible to handle the `U` and `const U &` specialisation in one piece of code or do I need to specialise everything twice?

Comment: @elemakil : Don't specialize for references, strip off the reference or use `value_type` as the answer suggests.

Comment: elemakil Agreed, @ildjarn is right! It should be possible to use some template magic to strip the reference if you're passing a reference type... I only ever used Boost.MPL, don't know how this translates into standard C++11

Comment: `std::remove_reference<>` is sensible.

Comment: @djf @ildjarn Thanks again. For now I've managed to use `value_type` or `tuple_element` to obtain the true type. But I'm still thinking about stripping the references for the sake of generalisation. I'll see whether it is required and decide based on that.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's all coming back to me now :)

As [ildjarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636019/ildjarn) hinted you can use `std::remove_reference` to strip the reference. I also stripped the `const` qualifier (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887144/stdremove-const-with-const-references)). My convenience struct looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct to_value
{
    typedef typename std::remove_const<
        typename std::remove_reference< T >::type
    >::type type;
};
```

You call it like this:

```
    typedef decltype( *it ) ContainedType;
    executioner< typename to_value<ContainedType>::type >::exec( *it );
```

Now you only need to specialize on the value type. Here's [the whole thing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b9462d28e7c4806).

Answer (score 0):

The typedef `ContainedType` is not `std::pair<int, std::string>`. It is `const std::pair<const int, std::string>&`. That is why your first partial specialization does not match. You can modify it that way:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct executioner<const std::pair<T1, T2>&> {
    inline static void exec( const std::pair<T1, T2> & t ) {
        std::cout << "pair" << std::endl;
        executioner<T1>::exec( t.first );
        executioner<T2>::exec( t.second );
    }
};
```

and it matches ([coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/291834978974ae43)).

Or you can use the `value_type` of the container, instead of `decltype(*it)`:

```
typedef typename Container<Ts...>::value_type ContainedType;
```

in the later case, `ContainedType` is `std::pair<const int, std::string>` as expected ([coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76366c8e1bc7a054)).