# std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>> does the order matter?

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

Does it matter in which order the following is applied ?

```
std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>>
```

*or*

```
std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
```

In what scenario, if any, does the order matter ?

Comment: Try to apply it to `const int&`. You should get `const int` in the first case and `int` in the second.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::remove\_const with const references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887144/stdremove-const-with-const-references)

Comment: @Evg I think it does somewhat, you are saying I should remove reference first, as references cannot be const ?

Comment: Exaclty. Loosely speaking, references cannot be non-"`const`".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are cases when these two type traits produce different results. For example, let's consider `T = const int&`.

1. `std::remove_cv_t` will remove top-level cv-qualifier, turning `const int&` into `const int&`, because there is no top-level cv-qualifier. `std::remove_reference_t` will then return `const int`.
2. In the second case, `std::remove_reference_t` will return `const int`, and `std::remove_cv_t` will transform it into `int`.

[Simple demo](https://godbolt.org/z/N6yNu8)