# Why MSVC still compiles to error for calling a method after removing const-ness of the object?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++14, compiler-bug

To avoid complexity, below is a minimal example. For some reason, I have to pass normal object as `const` to some method and use it as such:

```
#include<iostream>
#define CALL(OBJECT, METHOD) \
    const_cast<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(OBJECT)>>&>(OBJECT).METHOD()

struct X { void foo () { std::cout << "X::foo()\n"; } };
int main ()
{
  const X x;
  CALL(x,foo);
}
```

Above code compiles fine for g++ & clang++. However with [MSVC compiler](https://godbolt.org/) it results in below error:

> Left of `.foo()` must have a `class/struct/union`

Is this a compiler bug? What can be a workaround fix within that macro?

Comment: All compile fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9999PKjc4).

Comment: BTW, you might remove MACRO to simplify example.

Comment: You need "Share" a snippet to get a permalink. The browser address you give here is to the default landing page.

Comment: @Jarod42, somehow in my system MSVC2019 64-bit, along with Qt.  Above error is reproducing. Which compiler is in godbolt?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, sorry I just referred it. But in reality, what I saw was a runtime error as seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bT4r1qccW). In any case in my local system, above error comes.

Comment: There are a big possible selection of compiler version by compiler (I tend to test with latest, but not trunk).

Comment: `const_cast<X&>(x).foo();` would be simpler.

Comment: Notice that you have UB if `X::foo` does modify itself, as modifying const object is UB.

Comment: @Jarod42, the actual code is lot more complex than the above example. After lots of trial and error and referring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15887250), I have arrived to this solution, which works in all the platforms. Even in MSVC, it gives a spurious error, whch is not supposed to be. Regarding *UB*, the above code is only for demo purpose. In reality, a non-const object is passed as `const` at some places and then required to be called with the said method in special cases. So the source object is mutable.